# Preloader disappears before HTML finishes loading / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

Good morning,

I'm trying to create a page preloader using the tutorial linked, but it seems that I'm having a problem with the javascript part because my preloader gets hidden quickly while the rest of the page is still loading.

I'm not sure if the class "no-js" of html has something to do with it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuA83OYTE7I
tutorial used

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js animated fadeIn" lang="EN">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loader hidden">
<img src="../mirror/img/logo/LOGO_Loadscreen.gif" alt="loading logo">
</div>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main class="black-background">
    </main>

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.documentElement.className = 
        document.documentElement.className.replace("no-js","js");
    </script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
        window.ga=function(){ga.q.push(arguments)};ga.q=[];ga.l=+new Date;
        ga('create','UA-XXXXX-Y','auto');ga('send','pageview')
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
            console.log(loader);
            loader.className += " hidden"; // class "loader hidden"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
z-index: 12000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: var(--light-color);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.loader > img {
width: 80px;
}

.loader.hidden {
animation: fadeOut 1s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes fadeOut {
 100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the class `hidden` applied to the loader div.

Change `<div class="loader hidden">` to be `<div class="loader">`.

Then leave the javascript as it is and when the `"load"` event listener has been triggered it will add the `hidden` class and the loader will fade out.

Currently the img is showing untill the css has loaded at which point the `hidden` class affect is triggered, this explains why the results happen as expected but at the wrong time.